# Drag Telerik RadTreeview node to Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radtreeview

I want to drag a node from `Telerik RadTreeviw` to my `Textbox` in C# `winform`.
I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442372/enhanced-features-with-drag-and-drop-from-treeview-to-textbox-in-winforms) but it's for `Microsoft Treeview` and it's not working on `Telerik`, because `RadTreeview` just gets messy with this part

```
DoDragDrop(e.Node.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Does anyone knows a working solution in my case for `Telerik RadTreeView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to drag a node from RadTreeView to RadTextBox (can be replaced with the standard TextBox too, as in fact HostedTextBox is the standard one)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Point clickedPoint;
    bool mouseDown = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.AllowDrop = true;
        radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(HostedControl_DragEnter);
        radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(HostedControl_DragDrop);

        radTreeView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(radTreeView1_MouseDown);
        radTreeView1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(radTreeView1_MouseMove);

    }

    void HostedControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        RadTreeNode node = e.Data.GetData(typeof(RadTreeNode)) as RadTreeNode;
        if (node != null)
        {
            radTextBox1.Text = node.Text;
        }
    }

    void HostedControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    void radTreeView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown && IsRealDrag(e.Location, clickedPoint))
        {
            TreeNodeElement node = ((RadTreeView)sender).ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(clickedPoint) as TreeNodeElement;
            if (node != null)
            {
                ((RadTreeView)sender).DoDragDrop(node.Data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    void radTreeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            clickedPoint = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsRealDrag(Point mousePosition, Point initialMousePosition)
    {
        return (Math.Abs(mousePosition.X - initialMousePosition.X) >= SystemInformation.DragSize.Width) ||
            (Math.Abs(mousePosition.Y - initialMousePosition.Y) >= SystemInformation.DragSize.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! it's working fine. I also added some codes to it. It has a bug that happens in `MouseMove` event. I fixed it in my code

Answer (score 0):

I added some codes to @checho's so that I can drag & drop nodes in my `RadTreeView` without having to set its `AllowDragDrop=true`.

I added two `RadioButtons` to my form to change `Copy` and `Cut` mode when dragging between nodes.

Here's my code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Point clickedPoint;
    bool mouseDown = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.AllowDrop = true;
        radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(HostedControl_DragEnter);
        radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.HostedControl.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(HostedControl_DragDrop);

        radTreeView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(radTreeView1_MouseDown);
        radTreeView1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(radTreeView1_MouseMove);
    radTreeView1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(radTreeView1_DragEnter);
    radTreeView1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(radTreeView1_DragDrop);

    }

    void HostedControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        RadTreeNode node = e.Data.GetData(typeof(RadTreeNode)) as RadTreeNode;
        if (node != null)
        {
            radTextBox1.Text = node.Text;
        }
    }

    void HostedControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    void radTreeView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseDown && IsRealDrag(e.Location, clickedPoint))
        {
            TreeNodeElement node = ((RadTreeView)sender).ElementTree.GetElementAtPoint(clickedPoint) as TreeNodeElement;
            if (node != null)
            {
                ((RadTreeView)sender).DoDragDrop(node.Data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    }

    void radTreeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mouseDown = true;
            clickedPoint = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsRealDrag(Point mousePosition, Point initialMousePosition)
    {
        return (Math.Abs(mousePosition.X - initialMousePosition.X) >= SystemInformation.DragSize.Width) ||
            (Math.Abs(mousePosition.Y - initialMousePosition.Y) >= SystemInformation.DragSize.Height);
    }

    private void radTreeView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = radioButtonCopy.Checked ? DragDropEffects.Copy : DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void radTreeView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

            RadTreeNode sourceNode = e.Data.GetData(typeof(RadTreeNode)) as RadTreeNode;
            // Retrieve the client coordinates of the drop location.
            Point targetPoint = rtvTree.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            // Retrieve the node at the drop location.
            RadTreeNode targetNode = rtvTree.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
            if (sourceNode != null && targetNode != null)
            {
                RadTreeNode clonedNode = (RadTreeNode) sourceNode.Clone();
                if (radioButtonCut.Checked)
                    sourceNode.Remove();
                targetNode.Nodes.Add(clonedNode);
                targetNode.Expanded = true;
            }
     }
}
```